# What are the known results on the non-abelian Stark conjecture

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $L/K$ be a finite Galois extension of number fields with Galois group $G$, and let $\chi$ be a character of $G$. Let $c(\chi)$ be the leading coefficient of the Laurent series expansion of the Artin $L$-function $L(s,\chi)$ around $s=1$. Let $\exp_\infty^{-1}(\mathcal O_L^\times)$ be the inverse image of $\mathcal O_L^\times\subset(\mathbb R\otimes_\mathbb Q L)^\times$ under the exponential map
$$\mathbb R\otimes_\mathbb Q L=\prod_{w|\infty}L_w\xrightarrow{\exp_\infty}\prod_{w|\infty}L_w^\times=(\mathbb R\otimes_\mathbb Q L)^\times.$$
By the product formula, $\exp_\infty^{-1}(\mathcal O_L^\times)\subset\mathbb R L_0$, where $L_0=\{x\in L|{\rm tr}_{L/\mathbb Q}(x)=0\}.$ Moreover, $\exp_\infty^{-1}(\mathcal O_L^\times)$ is a lattice of $\mathbb R L_0$ and it indeed induces a $\mathbb C[G]$-linear isomorphism
$$\mu:\mathbb C\exp_\infty^{-1}(\mathcal O_L^\times)\simeq\mathbb CL_0.$$
Then $L_0$ and $\mathbb Q\exp_\infty^{-1}(\mathcal O_L^\times)$ are isomorphic as $\mathbb Q[G]$-modules, though not canonically. The complexification of any such $\mathbb Q[G]$-linear isomorphism $g:L_0\simeq\mathbb Q\exp_\infty^{-1}(\mathcal O_L^\times)$ is also denoted by $g:\mathbb C L_0\simeq\mathbb C\exp_\infty^{-1}(\mathcal O_L^\times)$. The automorphism $\mu\circ g$ on $\mathbb C L_0$ induces an automorphism $(\mu\circ g)_V$ on ${\rm Hom}_{\mathbb C[G]}(V,\;\mathbb CL_0).$ The regulator associated to $g$ is the determinant of this automorphism:
$$R(\chi,\;g)={\rm det}((\mu\circ g)_V).$$
Let $A(\chi,\,g)=R(\chi,\;g)/c(\chi).$ Stark conjectured the following.

(1) $A(\chi,\,g)\in\mathbb Q(\chi)$ where $\mathbb Q(\chi)=\mathbb Q(\chi(g)|\,g\in G)$.

(2) For any $\sigma\in{\rm Gal}(\mathbb Q(\chi)/\mathbb Q)$, we have $\sigma(A(\chi,\,g))=A(\sigma\circ\chi,\,g)$.

What are the known results about the above conjecture?